# Scroll column-wise horizontally on clicking Prev/Next in bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I created 2 buttons that scroll the DIV left and right. However, it scrolls a fixed width. I want it to scroll each column of Bootstrap 5 on clicking Prev/Next.

or in simpler terms, I want it to scroll one column each to the left or right as per the click and not 100px each as it currently does. Please help.

**DEMO JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hsmx2f5z/**

HTML

```
<div class="nav-scroller">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row nav" id="boxSlider">
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 1</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 2</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 3</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 4</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 5</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 nav-scroller__eighty">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5><a href="#">Title 6</a></h5>
                <p>Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider. Some information about the slider.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input id="btnLeft" type="Button" value="Prev"/>
<input id="btnRight" type="Button" value="Next" />
```

CSS:

```
.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.nav-underline .nav-link {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #6c757d;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.nav-underline .nav-link:hover {
  color: #007bff;
}
.card-body p {
  color: #393939;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.nav-underline .active {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #343a40;
}
.nav-scroller__eighty {
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

JS:

```
const boxSlider = document.getElementById('boxSlider');

document.getElementById("btnLeft").onclick = () => {
  boxSlider.scroll({
         left: boxSlider.scrollLeft + 200,
         behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
     
document.getElementById("btnRight").onclick = () => {
  boxSlider.scroll({
         left: boxSlider.scrollLeft - 200,
         behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to scroll based on the width of the column elements, like this:

```js
  boxSlider.scroll({
    left: boxSlider.scrollLeft + widthOfColumn,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
```

You can get the width of a column like this:

```js
// Assuming all columns are the same width, get the width of the first column
boxSlider.querySelector(".nav-scroller__eighty").offsetWidth
```

Your code should look something like this

```js
const boxSlider = document.getElementById('boxSlider');

document.getElementById("btnLeft").onclick = () => {
  boxSlider.scroll({
    left: boxSlider.scrollLeft + boxSlider.querySelector(".nav-scroller__eighty").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
     
document.getElementById("btnRight").onclick = () => {
  boxSlider.scroll({
    left: boxSlider.scrollLeft - boxSlider.querySelector(".nav-scroller__eighty").offsetWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

Comment: This works but I forgot to mention that there are 5 different such scrollers and I believe we can't use more than 1 `id="boxSlider"`. Is there any solution so that?

Comment: @ElaineByene if you have more than 1 just call the next one botSlider2, or label them under a class and make a loop to do the same thing.

Comment: With this answer, you can style, adjust and clean the code and the HTML anyway you want. Works perfectly in Bootstrap 5 as long as you keep the Javascript intact. In fact: leaving out the prev/next buttons makes it a seriously great mobile scrolling solution to use when styling it to your needs with (Bootstrap) CSS. You can even set the 'nav-scroller__eighty' as a Bootstrap button.